# simulation of a governing mathematical equation using python

Tags: python, simulation, differential-equations

I am running a simulation based on moving mass involving rayleigh beam system with elastic pasternack inner layer and supported by elastic restrain end using this governing equation

```
El (∂^4 W_1 (x,t))/(∂x^4 )+ μ (∂^2 W_1 (x,t))/(∂t^2 )- T_(c_1  )^r μR_1   (∂^4 W_1 (x,t))/(∂x^2  ∂t^2 )  + T_(c_2)^r  [K_1 [W_1  (x,t)- W_2 (x,t)]- G_1 [(∂^2 W_1 (x,t))/(∂x^2 )- (∂^2 W_2 (x,t))/(∂x^2 )] ]  = F_1 (x,t)
```

The following boundaries to be used are

```
(∂^2 W_1 (x,t))/(∂x^2 )=0= (∂^2 W_1 (L,t))/(∂x^2 )  
El (∂^3 W_i (0,t))/(∂x^3 )=  K_1 W_i (0,t);i=1,2
El (∂^3 W_i (L,t))/(∂x^3 )=  K_1 W_i (L,t);i=1,2
The corresponding initial conditions are
〖W_1(x,t)  |〗_(t=0)= 0,〖(∂^2 W_1 (x,t))/(∂t^2 )  |〗_(t=0)  =0
〖W_2(x,t)  |〗_(t=0)= 0,〖(∂^2 W_2 (x,t))/(∂t^2 )  |〗_(t=0)  =0
```

I have tried running this in jupyter notebook with the help of chat gpt which used methods like finite element method (FEM), Crank-Nicolson method and Finite Difference Method (FDM). The resulting plot produced a straight line

Comment: To better understand the issue you're facing, could you please provide more details about the simulation setup and parameters you used for the finite element method (FEM), Crank-Nicolson method, and finite difference method (FDM)?